# Create Event Scheduler in MySQL that drops user

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and want to create event scheduler in MySQL that drops user whose name starts with user%. The scheduler should run every Wednesday and Friday at 10 AM EST.

Comment: You need to clarify the question to make it clear what the question actually is and where you are having difficulty. –

Comment: DROP USER is allowed in prepared statements, hence it is allowed in Event Procedures. So you may create Event Procedure which performs described action.

Comment: *The scheduler should run every Wednesday and Friday at 10 AM EST.* Create SP which performs the action. Create EP which calls this SP - either 2 separate EPs which are fired weekly, or one SP fired daily which checks current weekday.

Comment: @akina question is not clear but OPs problem might be 'starts with user%. ' ie drop multiple users

Comment: @P.Salmon - I understand the complete flow of logic. My ask is simple to help me with the code since I am new to MySQL.

Comment: @P.Salmon I do not see the problem there. DROP USER must be executed one-by-one. So cursor by mysql.user and iteration over it with prepared stmt.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. You need to make a good faith attempt to solve this on your own, then post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.